# React Higher Order Components

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, higher-order-components

I created this HOC that a user can pass in two components, and it returns a font awesome stack icons.

```
const StackIcons = (BaseIcon, TopIcon) => (props) => {
   const { container, base, top } = props;
   return (
    <span className={`fa-stack fa-lg fa-${container}`}>
        <BaseIcon stack="2x" className="info" {...base} />
        <TopIcon stack="1x" isInverse={true} {...top} />
    </span>
   );
};
```

I need to distinguish the different props between the container, base icon, and top icon, so I decided to pass an object that has a property for container (string), base (object), and top (object).

For example,

```
const object = {
  container: 'lg',
  base: {
    stack: '2x',
    className: 'info'
  },
  top: {
    stack: '1x',
    isInverse: true
  }
}
```

My biggest problem with this approach is the fact the propTypes and defaultProps are not working.

```
// StackIcons.defaultProps = {
//     base: {
//         stack: '2x',
//         className: 'info'
//     },
//     top: {
//         stack: '1x',
//         isInverse: true
//     },
//     container: 'lg'
// };

StackIcons.propTypes = {
    base: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    top: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    container: PropTypes.oneOf(['lg', '2x', '3x', '4x', '5x']).isRequired,
};
```

Since the defaultProps are not working, I decided to commented them out and hard-coded the props for base and top icon components, but then the consumer can override the default props by passing in the appropriate props.

usage:

```
 const StackedIcons = StackIcons(<CircleIcon />, <DollarSign />);

 // in render method
 <StackedIcons /> // use default props

 // or override the defaultProps.
 <StackedIcons container="..." base={{...}} top={{...}} />
```

1. How to fix the propTypes and defaultTypes?
2. Is there a better way?

I did tried something like this:

```
const StackIcons = (BaseIcon) => (baseIconProps) => (TopIcon) => (topIconProps) => {...}
```

But I wasn't a fan of doing this:

```
const StackedIcons = StackIcons(<CircleIcon />)({ stack: '12x', className: 'info' })(<DollarSign />)

// in render method
<StackedIcons stack="1x" isInverse={true} />
```

**A big thanks to Yury Tarabanko!**
**Here is my updated working version:**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const stackIcons = (BaseIcon, TopIcon) => {

    const StackIcons = (props) => {
        const {container, base, top} = props;
        return (
            <span className={`fa-stack fa-lg fa-${container}`}>
                <BaseIcon {...base} />
                <TopIcon {...top} />
            </span>
        );
    };

    StackIcons.defaultProps = {
        base: {
            stack: '2x',
            className: 'info'
        },
        top: {
            stack: '1x',
            isInverse: true
        },
        container: 'lg'
    };

    StackIcons.propTypes = {
        base: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        top: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        container: PropTypes.oneOf(['lg', '2x', '3x', '4x', '5x']).isRequired,
    };

    return StackIcons;
};

export default stackIcons;
```

Comment: whats not working with `defaultProps `?

Comment: If I uncomment the defaultProps, and I get rid of stack, className, and isInverse props for both base and top icons, the style for fontawesome isn't working. Also, if the propTypes are all required, and once again, I get rid of the stack, className, and isInverse props for both the base and top icons, and then pass nothing as props, the isRequired isn't working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set `propTypes` on `StackIcons` because it is not a component. It returns component. So you need to set `propTypes` on returned component.

```
const StackIcons = (BaseIcon, TopIcon) => {

   const Wrapped = props => ...

   Wrapped.propTypes = {}

   Wrapped.defaultProps = {}

   return Wrapped
};
```

Usage should be

```
 // here StackIcons is HOC
 // you can't use it like <StackIcons/>
 // but StackedIcons is just a stateless component
 const StackedIcons = StackIcons(CircleIcon, DollarSign);

 // so you can use it like this
 <StackedIcons /> // use default props

 // or override the defaultProps.
 <StackedIcons container="..." base={{...}} top={{...}} />
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not a component, but it returns a component?

Comment: What else could this mean other than this function is not a component? It is Higher Order Component that **returns a component** on which you want to specify prop types and such.

Comment: Ok, I get it! Thanks

Comment: @FNMT8L9IN82 No problem. :)